# Python: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' and TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'list', cleanest way to code this?

Tags: python-2.7, list, function, floating-point, sequence

I have a set-up that looks something like this, and am running into some problems when I try to call a function after doing some matrix math. I wanted to see if there was a more efficient way to do this:

```
   #Define functions
   def function_7(func_7):
       func_7 = []
       func_7.append([ [ [0,0], [0, -func7] ] ])
       return func7_

   def function_5(func_5):
       func_5 = []
       slope_func5 = 1/math.sqrt(3)
       theta = math.atan(slope_func5)
       x_func5 = func_5*math.cos(theta)
       y_func5 = func_5*math.sin(theta)
       func_5.append( [ [[0, x_func5], [0, y_func5]], [[0, -x_func5], [0, y_func5]] ] )
       return func_5_

   func5_list = []
   func7_list = []

   #Set up matrix here
   my_list = (0, 10, 1)

   for i in my_list:
       A = np.matrix( [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                       [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1.5, 1.5],
                       [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.5],
                       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
      B = lambda i: np.matrix([[3], [8], [6], [12], [5], [i]])
      var = np.linalg.solve(A, B(i))

      func7_list.append(function_7(float(var[1,:]))
      func5_list.append(function_5(float(var[2,:]))
```

When I try to call on function_7 and append something to func7_list, I get this error:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'list'
```

When I try to call on function_5 and append something to func5_list, I get this error:

```
 TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I know it must be a problem with how I'm generating the lists - I tried iterating through the values of func5_list and func7_list calling my earlier functions there, but that didn't work either. Any suggestions on how to call the function for each value of var[1,:] or var[2,:] and return a list of outputs? Thank you!

edit: Figured out the problem. It was with calling on a variable that was already being used.

Comment: var is a list, right?

Comment: It is a list with matrix outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I did some modifications in your code. Your code has lot of problems including indentations and missing paranthesis.

```
def function_7(func_7):
   func_7 = []
   func_7.append([ [ [0,0], [0, -func7] ] ])
   return func7

def function_5(func_5):
   func_5 = []
   slope_func5 = 1/math.sqrt(3)
   theta = math.atan(slope_func5)
   x_func5 = func_5*math.cos(theta)
   y_func5 = func_5*math.sin(theta)
   func_5.append( [ [[0, x_func5], [0, y_func5]], [[0, -x_func5], [0, y_func5]] ] )
   return func_5

func5_list = []
func7_list = []

#Set up matrix here
my_list = (0, 10, 1)

for i in my_list:
    A = np.matrix( [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                     [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1.5, 1.5],
                     [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.5],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
    B = lambda i: np.matrix([[3], [8], [6], [12], [5], [i]])
    var = np.linalg.solve(A, B(i))
    func7_list.extend(map(float, var[1:]))
    func5_list.extend(map(float, var[2:]))
```

You needed to map float function on the var list and then extend the lists with the outputs as above.

Comment: Thanks, this helps not give an error. However, it doesn't print out func5_list or func7_list correctly, like what those functions are supposed to return. 

I would want them to give entries in the format of: [ [ [0,0], [0, -func7] ] ] or [ [[0, x_func5], [0, y_func5]], [[0, -x_func5], [0, y_func5]] ]. Do you know how to do that? I have updated my first post with how I want the function to call on each output of the for loop.

Comment: When I create a new list (func7_test) and try to append like this: func7_test.append(function_7(func7_list)) I still get the same errors as before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below. It seems to be working fine on my PC

```
import numpy as np
#Define functions
def function_7(func_7):
    func_7 = []
    func_7.append([ [ [0,0], [0, -func7] ] ])
    return func7

def function_5(func_5):
    func_5 = []
    slope_func5 = 1/math.sqrt(3)
    theta = math.atan(slope_func5)
    x_func5 = func_5*math.cos(theta)
    y_func5 = func_5*math.sin(theta)
    func_5.append( [ [[0, x_func5], [0, y_func5]], [[0, -x_func5], [0, y_func5]] ] )
    return func_5

func5_list = []
func7_list = []

#Set up matrix here
my_list = (0, 10, 1)

for i in my_list:
    A = np.matrix( [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                   [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1.5, 1.5],
                   [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.5],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
    B = lambda i: np.matrix([[3], [8], [6], [12], [5], [i]])
    #print B(i)
    var = np.linalg.solve(A, B(i))
    #print var
    func7_list.append(float(var[1,:]))
    func5_list.append(float(var[2,:]))
print func5_list
print func7_list
```

Output:
[0.33333333333333304, -9.666666666666668, -0.666666666666667]
[6.333333333333334, 11.333333333333334, 6.833333333333334]

Comment: Sorry I've updated my first entry, I actually want something like this, where the function acts on each entry of the for loop:  func7_list.append(function_7(float(var[1,:]))). This is where I'm getting the errors.